# Azure PowerShell start Virtual Machine with RBAC

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

In the new Azure portal you have the option to use Role Based Access (RBAC). I want to give a user rights to startup and shutdown a virtual machine in Azure. I also don't want that is it possible for this user to create new VM's in Azure so I don't want to make this user Administrator. I gave the user the required rights in the new Azure portal (owner for: the VM, Cloud Service and storage).

When I open PowerShell with the user that has rights on Azure. I first execute the command `Add-AzureAccount`. After this I execute the following command: `Start-AzureVM -ServiceName "MyVM" -Name "MyVM"`. Then I receive the following error: `ForbiddenError: The server failed to authenticate the request. Verify that the certificate is valid and is associated with this subscription.`

When I perform this scenario for a Subscription Administrator everything works fine.

Is the described scenario supported by the Azure PowerShell cmdlets? What are possible alternatives?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using a classic VM or a new one (created in the new portal)? If you're using a new one, currently you have to switch mode via Switch-AzureMode AzureResourceManager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, RBAC through Powershell is currently only available for ARM-resources, i.e. non-"classic" resources in the preview portal, and users needs to have accounts in the Azure AD tenant associated with the subscription. Federated Microsoft accounts will won't work.